# Using Python to Scrape Data Between Patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a data set, and I want to grab certain aspects of the data. For the first line and the first word if it is equal to `regex = re.compile(r'\A([A-Z][a-z][A-Z]\w*[-]\w*')`. How would I scrape that data between the lines (which are dashes) and keep the data with the line and remove the data that identifier that is not equal "regex".

For example: I want to keep the data within `AbD000000-10` and `DeD000000-10` but not `888888-10`.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AbD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
888888-10
         Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DeD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to see my output to look like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AbD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DeD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I do this in python?

I am able to grab all the information inside but is there a way to create segments of data that I can then play with.

Thank you!

Comment: Do the AbD000000-10 and DeD000000-10 records always consist of two physical lines? Does the 888888-10 record always consist of one physical line? Are there any records with different types?

Comment: There is no consistency between the identifiers only that the ones I want to grab follow the pattern of: uppercase-lowercase-uppercase and are the first "word" in the first line after the dashed lines.

Comment: In order to process the segments, can you show us what you see when you grab this data including any tags that might populate in your current output?

Comment: Sure. Right now I am only grabbing the data the identifiers that are in the regex:

Comment: So it just displays in a prettytable = [Key, Error, ID] ([AbD000000-10 , DeD000000-10]) after the list for Error and ID is empty because it is grabbing 6 issues instead of 4 because I do not have an restraints to only selected the data up until the next dashed line. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your regex is broken (that `\A` doesn't belong).

In this approach, I assume that the separator will always be the same.  I assume you don't want to break the blocks down any further.  This grabs only the blocks you want.  You can format them however is convenient (including printing the separator back out when you print the blocks).

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z][A-Z]\w*[-]\w*')
sep = "#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------#"
input_text = """
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

AbD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
888888-10
         Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
DeD000000-10
Issue 1  
Issue 2          Q             Q            Q 
ID: 2             MsEhdiehsla2 MsEhasdhsla2  hiGndiehsla2
ID: 3 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
"""
s = input_text.split(sep)
keep = [x for x in s if re.search(r , x)]

for v in keep:
    print(v)
```

Really, though, if you can help it, it would be good to consume this data from a better source.  If this is a log file, you may not have a lot of control over it.  But if you can, see if you can get a cleaner source of the data (csv maybe?).

Comment: It can only be a text file. Here is a better example of the data: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnnzjKQTUrDggzeBEneXRZC6yoqN

Comment: So in my case i have data = open("data.txt", "r") so i am getting the error file object has no attribute split. Is there a way to have the same result but with a file? Thank you!

Comment: Even when I use input_text and I get: AttributeErrorr: 'str' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Now it is saying AttributeErrorr: builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Hard to debug without knowing what, specifically, you're doing.  Could you update the OP with your revisions?